# Item name and quantity are not passing to accepted order table in web page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a page where orders from `New orders` table get passed to `Accepted orders` table. [Here is the link.](http://jsfiddle.net/o0pt54c6/5/)
I'm unable to pass `item name` and `quantity` from `new orders` table to `Accepted orders` table. Item name is the name of food and quantity is the badge. I want to pass those values from `New orders` table to `Accepted orders` table. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accptOrdr').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).parent().parent().children().filter(':first-child');
       /*var text = $(this).parent().parent().children().filter(':second-child');*/
        var thisTr = text.parent();
        /*var thisTrOne = text.parent();*/
        console.log($('.table.accepted-orders'));
        $('.accepted-orders').append('<div class="well well-sm order col-md-5"><div>Time remaining: 20 minutes</div> <div class="pull-left">' + text.text() + '</div><table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Note</th></tr></thead><tr><td>  </td> <td>  </td> </tr> </table> <div class="pull-right"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btns">Completed</button> </div></div>');
        thisTr.remove();
        /*thisTrOne.remove();*/
    });
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Anybody here who can help me? I'm unable to do it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/o0pt54c6/6/embedded/result/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, you almost nailed it. But I'd remove `x 1` from `kaafi-nirvana x 1`

Comment: The name of food item is `kaafi-nirvana`, not `kaafi-nirvana x 1`. So I would expect a result of `kaafi-nirvana` to be passed to `Accepted orders` table

Comment: try this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/o0pt54c6/8/embedded/result/)

Comment: Better than old one... Is it possible to split `order id`and `order time` in `Accepted table` so that `order id` comes in a single line and `order time` comes in next line? Is it possible to pass the whole badge instead of passing only the value of badge?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/o0pt54c6/9/embedded/result/